# selecting the first of multiple classes

Tags: jquery

Not sure if you can do this, but I want to select the first of two classes of an element with jQuery and return it's first class only.

```
<div class="module blue">
```

I want to return 'module'.

tried this:

```
var state = $('body').attr('class').first();
```

but none of that seems to work, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
var class = $('.module').attr('class');
var st = class.split(' ');
var firstClass = st[0];
```

Comment: rocking! thanks guys, a bit of sleep and advice and it all makes sense :-)

Answer (score 4):

Once you have a reference to the element, simply get it's className attribute and split it by space, and then you'll have the first class at [0] in the split array:

```
var className = $(element).attr('class'),
    split = className.split(/\s+/g);

alert(split[0] || 'Empty className');
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a one liner?

```
var state = $('body').attr('class').replace(/\s.+$/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the first attribute.

You can try

```
<div class="category">A</div>
<div class="category">B</div>
```

I have two input field with same class name I can select the first one by following code

```
//I have added trigger function which might not be needed
$(".category").first().trigger('click')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, it selects the first element matching that class, yes. But the question is asking how to extract the first class name itself from a given element